# Where is the energy coming from in a see saw?

Tags: energy-conservation

In this video: https://www.facebook.com/mytopfm/videos/10152482869686147/ two people are on either side of a see saw going quite high.

As they continue to fall they keep seeming to go just as high. In this closed system shouldn't lots of energy be lost every jump?

Where is the energy coming from to keep them going just as high every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look carefully at the video, every time one of them is preparing to be launched upwards, they are also jumping. They are expending energy with their leg muscles. That is the source of extra energy that compensates for losses.